# Program outputting 2^n instead of intended

Tags: c

I was recently trying to make a small program in c to find the nth fibannaci number. For some reason, when I run it it instead does the calculation of 2^n and returns that, I have asked around a bit but no one seems to have been able to determine why. I was hoping someone may be able to help me figure it out.

```
float wat(int n){
  int a = 0x3fcf1bbd, b = 0x3f1e377a, c = 0x807fffff, d = 0x400f1bbd;
  int e = (((a >> 23) + n) << 23) | (a & c);
  int f = (((b >> 23) + n) << 23) | (b & c);
  return ((*(float*)&e) + (*(float*)&f))/(*(float*)&d);
}
```

Comment: Explain why you think this code should give you the nth fibonacci number

Comment: @samgak It is based on a few things. First being the formula for the nth fibannaci number being (Phi^n-phi^n)/sqrt(5). Phi being (1+sqrt(5))/2 and phi being (1-sqrt(5))/2. 'a' is Phi in hexadecimal and 'b' is a non negative phi in hex. 'c' is a bitmask for isolating the exponent bits of a float, and 'd' is just sqrt(5) in hex. I am trying to add n to the exponent value then recombine to form a new value. Then by doing float math, combine the two floats then divide by the sqrt(5) as a float to mirror the formula I stated earlier.

Comment: Adding 1 to the exponent is the same as multiplying by 2. Adding `n` multiplies by `2^n`. So I don't see how this is supposed to work.

Answer (score 3):

Your code is a standards violating, unportable hack that might have been meaningful 20 years ago in very special situations and when floating point hardware was magnitudes slower than the rest of the cpu. It's completely meaningless today and asking someone today to debug it for you is like asking for help to insulate your house with asbestos. We don't do things this way anymore, for good reasons.

It can all be written in correct, portable floating point operations like this:

```
#include <math.h>
float
wat(int n)
{
        float a = 0x1.9e377ap+0;
        float b = -0x1.3c6ef4p-1;
        float d = 0x1.1e377ap+1;
        return (ldexpf(a, n) - ldexpf(b, n)) / d;
}
```

This does exactly the same thing, but without disgusting hacks. Of course it won't do anything useful because adding `n` to the exponent of X doesn't do `X^n`, it does `X*2^n`. So your calculation ends up being:

```
s = sqrt(5)
(2^n * (1 + s)/2 - 2^n * (1 - s)/2)/s = 
(2^n/2 * ((1 + s) - (1 - s)))/s = 
2^n
```

Comment: Is there any reason to not compute the float constants using `sqrt`, or to expect people will recognize what's going on in hex rather than in decimal?

Comment: @TheVee I would write the constants with sqrt and hope that the compiler calculates them at compile time, or not but still have human-readable code. I wouldn't write them decimal, because I want them exact. But in this case I wanted the code to match the code in the question, including magic constants, except correct.